# SQL Server: how to calculate beddays over different capacity periods

Tags: sql-server, select, case, calculation

In SQL Server 2008, I need to produce a SQL report with parameters where users can enter `Startdate`, `Enddate` and `Department name`; and the result they get is the possible bed occupation for this period. I can then compare it to the actual (realized) bed occupation which gives information about the efficiency of the department.

Given this table `@@Temptable01`:

```
Department_name Bed_Capacity    CAP_Startdate   CAP_Enddate
------------------------------------------------------------
Dept_ A              20           1-1-2015      31-12-2015
Dept_ A              22           1-1-2016      31-8-2016
Dept_ B              21           1-1-2015      Null
Dept_ C              30           1-1-2017      30-6-2017
Dept_ A              24           1-9-2016      Null
Dept_ C              32           1-7-2017      Null
```

The possible bed occupation (bed days) could be calculated in a select statement by using

```
Bed_Capacity * (enddate – startddate)
```

A problems arises when a report period is chosen which overlaps multiple periods with different capacity.

I am thinking about using case statements like following:

```
 Select 
     Department_name, 
     (case when startdate between CAP_Startdate and CAP_Enddate 
                      and (enddate between CAP_Startdate and CAP_Enddate 
                           or CAP_Enddate is null) 
              then Bed_Capacity * (Enddate – CAP_Startdate)) as beddays 
From 
    @@Temptable01
```

This is obviously not complete (or even correct) but I can’t seem to figure out the right approach. Somehow I need to determine the number of days that the period overlaps with each capacity-category then multiply with that capacity and add them all up

Can anyone give me any suggestions?

Comment: Your period is based on your parameters. The question is, do you need to omit days outside of the defined CAP ranges which fall between your parameter range?

Comment: Yes. But the CAP ranges will Always connect. If no Cap range exists with CAP_enddate of Null  it means the department ceased to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not work out the number of overlapping days using the DATEDIFF function?

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
 Department NVARCHAR(10),
 BedCapacity INT,
 CAP_StartDate DATE,
 CAP_EndDate DATE)

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
 ('Dept_ A', 20,'2015-01-01', '2015-12-31'),
 ('Dept_ A', 22,'2016-01-01', '2016-08-31'),
 ('Dept_ B', 21,'2015-01-01', NULL),
 ('Dept_ C', 30,'2017-01-01', '2017-06-30'),
 ('Dept_ A', 24,'2016-09-01', NULL),
 ('Dept_ C', 32,'2017-07-01', NULL)

DECLARE 
 @StartDate DATE = '2015-03-01',
 @EndDate DATE = '2016-02-28'

SELECT 
 *,
 t.BedCapacity * DATEDIFF(DAY, 
 CASE WHEN t.CAP_StartDate > @StartDate THEN t.CAP_StartDate ELSE @StartDate END, 
 CASE WHEN COALESCE(t.CAP_EndDate, @EndDate) < @EndDate THEN t.CAP_EndDate ELSE @EndDate END) Total
FROM @t t
WHERE t.CAP_StartDate <= @EndDate
 AND COALESCE(t.CAP_EndDate, @EndDate) >= @StartDate
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer i was hoping for. Thanks a lot. You saved me a lot of time!